# CISCO Aironet 1140 not responding after updating duplex settings

Tags: access-point

I update the duplex mode/speed settings for my CISCO aironet 1140 AP from Auto/Auto to Full/1000. It is now not responding to ping or connecting via URL. I am trying to get it back to Auto/Auto so that it works.

Any suggestions?

This url shows the screen where I made the change.

http://d.pr/i/Pjjb

Comment: Why would you do that?! Did you set the other end to Full/1000 too? Because it obviously won't work if one side is trying to negotiate and the other isn't. Also, make 100% sure the cable is correct for Gigabit (all four pairs wired through and correct pin assignments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the switch it is plugged into is manageable check the settings on that port.  Does the switch port even support gigabit?  If it does, it and the aironet should be set to auto and it will negotiate gigabit on its own.

Gigabit ports should be set to autonegotiate regardless.  See here: http://etherealmind.com/ethernet-autonegotiation-works-why-how-standard-should-be-set/

> A major problem is that many people are also hard setting Gigabit
>   Ethernet , and this is causing major problems. Gigabit Ethernet must
>   have auto-negotation ENABLED to allow negotiation of master / slave
>   PHY relationshitwhp for clocking at the physical layer. Without
>   negotiation the line clock will not establish correctly and physical
>   layers problems can result.

If you still have no access to the AP, you will need to manage it directly.  The easiest way to do this would be to connect it directly to your laptop via a small static network if you know the APs IP address already.  Otherwise you'll need to "console" into it: https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-2320

Comment: Thanks Cleaner. As an update, for some reason even consoling into the unit wouldn't give the normal screen so I had to do a reset of the AP. Once I did that, it showed up in the Console connection, saw the DHCP address, logged in via the web address and uploaded a file of a backup configuration I had taken a few months ago. Now it's working again. Looks like the "inline" or POE update got it stuck in some type of boot no man's land.